# how to run a graphical program via CLI?

Tags: command-line, scripts, graphics, ssh, php

I have a program (k40-whisperer.py) which is graphical using tk(). I added CLI functionality, and it works when I am running it via a computer with a display.

I want to run it via an exec() function, such as over ssh, or via php exec commands. The problem is that when I do this, I get display related errors.

```
$ laser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./k40_whisperer.py", line 3855, in <module>
    root = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1822, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "0.0"
```

I tried setting the display port, with an `ssh -X` session, but it doesnt like this, and I do not actually want it either.

I tried adding:

```
import matplotlib    
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

after reading that matplotlib assigns its own display ports, but I still get the same error. What other methods exist for execution of a graphical program via a shell? Again, I do not want, or care to have a GUI at any point, I just want to send cli arguments to the program, and have it run.

You can assume removing all references to tk() GUI object would be extreemely tedious.

in the spirit of editing the source to suppress graphical output, I tried `root.withdraw()` which still has the same error, even though a window is not displayed while running the source-code in a graphical session.

where the initializtion of tkinter happens in these lines of code:

```
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
app = Application(root)
```

Comment: Is there a GUI on that server in the first place ? ( Which also is a big security no-no)

Comment: I see it's Python. Try to wrap the offending code into `try...except...` block with `pass` in `except` part. Also, this really sounds like the script needs rewriting.

Comment: Install and use [xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb). `xvfb-run laser`

Comment: xvfb-run might work. .. is there a way to get stdout? I am away form the laser hardware right now, I cannot test this yet.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy there is no gui on the server,  but I am developing the code on my Ubuntu laptop,  which is why i did not encounter this issue sooner.